# If one periodic orbit is attracting then $T$ is not topologically transitive

Tags: general-topology, analysis, dynamical-systems

Any ideas, hints on the following would be great.

> Suppose that $T\colon X \to X$ is continuous, and there exist at least two distinct periodic orbits.
>   Show that if one of the periodic orbits is attracting then $T$ is not topologically transitive.

Note that the definition of attracting is: If $\Gamma = O(x)$ is the periodic orbit then there is and open set $U$ containing $\Gamma$ such that $\omega(x') = \Gamma$ for every $x' \in U$.

It may be assumed that $X$ is compact.

Comment: What's $\omega$?

Comment: Let the attracting orbit be $A$, the other periodic orbit, $B$. Choose an open set $U$ containing $A$ and "small enough" that $T(U)\subseteq U$ (I'm imagining $X$ to be a metric space; I'm not quite sure how to phrase then in a more general setting). Choose an open set $V$ containing the other periodic orbit and disjoint from $U$. Then $T^k(U)\cap V$ is empty for all $U$. I'm a bit out of my depth here and not confident enough to leave this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's see.  Let $U$ is a non-empty open set with the property that every point in $U$ converges to the attractive orbit.  If the transformation is topologically transitive, then 
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} T^k(U)$$
covers the space.  Must be a contradiction right about there, seeing as how one of the $T^k(U)$s must contain a point in the other orbit.

Comment: @Gerry Ah yes, \union - very clever of me.  I typeset with Mathematica more than LaTeX these days and it gets so confusing.

Comment: I think there's something better than what I used --- maybe \bigcup --- but I don't have my TeX book handy. You could experiment. I note that your answer bears a resemblance to my comment, but is much cleaner.

Comment: Yep - I think your comment appeared while I was typing.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I am unable to see why $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty T^k(U)$ is the whole of $X$. I can see that it is dense in $X$. Can you please explain this. Thanks.